# Rendering icons within tds on same line as select/input elements

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I'm rendering a table, and dynamically adding a font awesome icon into the td, appending as a sibling to my select/input element.

For some reason, I can't get these two elements to be on the same line within the td.

I've tried nowrap, inline, inline-block, spans, etc.

This is rendered by a django formset, also.

Here's some code for context but its pretty generic. This isn't super original...but I'm not accustomed to working with tables so hopefully it's just something silly that I don't know:

```
<table>
     <thead></thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <div>
              <select class='form-control'></select>
              <i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS?

Comment: i'm in a project that exclusively uses bootstrap 4/crispy-form-fields --- I'm adding/removing classes and css using jquery

Comment: That's great, but it we see what you have tried already to achieve this effect, we can help yo better in altering the HTML and the CSS accordingly .